# Grouping field not appears on admin of Linked Products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have two versions of my site to test some plugins:

**- beta)** wordpress 3.7.4 + woocommerce 2.1.12

So, on admin of a product -> Product Data -> Linked Products, it shows the fields "up-sells", "cross sells" and "grouping". Fine.

**- alpha)** wordpress 4.0 + woocommerce 2.2.6

On the same admin page, it shows the fields "up-sells" and "cross-sells", but **don't show "grouping"** field. The field appears on Inspect Element but it is hidden with inline `display:none`.

--

Looking on code, I've found this:

```
// wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/admin/meta-boxes-product.js
138: $( hide_classes ).show();
139: $( show_classes ).hide();
```

Maybe this can be a bug? Or maybe some configuration I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Grouping* field in *Linked Products* is hidden when you're editing products of the types *Variable* and *Grouped*. This means that the reason that you didn't see that field on your newer installation might have been that you were editing a product of one of those types.

When you want to set the group name for a grouped product in order to associate simple products to it you actually do not need the *Grouping* field because the grouped product name itself serves as the name of the group.

According to this logic, all you need to do in order to make the association is to type the grouped item's name in the *Grouping* field for each simple product that you are associating and you're done.